# Declaration is incompatible with type

Tags: c++, string, types

header file:

```
#ifndef H_bankAccount;
#define H_bankAccount;


class bankAccount
{
public:
    string getAcctOwnersName() const;
    int getAcctNum() const;
    double getBalance() const;
    virtual void print() const;

    void setAcctOwnersName(string);
    void setAcctNum(int);
    void setBalance(double);

    virtual void deposit(double)=0;
    virtual void withdraw(double)=0;
    virtual void getMonthlyStatement()=0;
    virtual void writeCheck() = 0;
private:
    string acctOwnersName;
    int acctNum;
    double acctBalance;
};
#endif
```

cpp file:

```
#include "bankAccount.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;


string bankAccount::getAcctOwnersName() const
{
    return acctOwnersName;
}
int bankAccount::getAcctNum() const
{
    return acctNum;
}
double bankAccount::getBalance() const
{
    return acctBalance;
}
void bankAccount::setAcctOwnersName(string name)
{
    acctOwnersName=name;
}
void bankAccount::setAcctNum(int num)
{
    acctNum=num;
}
void bankAccount::setBalance(double b)
{
    acctBalance=b;
}
void bankAccount::print() const
{
    std::cout << "Name on Account: " << getAcctOwnersName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Account Id: " << getAcctNum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Balance: " << getBalance() << std::endl;
}
```

Please help i get an error under getAcctOwnersName, and setAcctOwnersName stating that the declaration is incompatible with "< error-type > bankAccount::getAcctOwnersName() const".

Comment: As presented, the code should not compile, as the header file doesn't include `<string>`. I think the problem might be the header picking up a different meaning of `string` than `std::string`. Try putting `#include <string>` into the header and use `std::string` instead of plain `string` there. See if that helps.

Comment: Unless that's the *first* error your compiler displays, you're probably best off ignoring it. Always work through the list of errors from top to bottom; don't start at the last one it prints, even though that's the one that's easiest to find in the output. Often, one mistake early in a program can cause a cascade of errors later, and it does no good to try to fix the later ones without addressing the one that triggered them all in the first place.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to

```
#include <string>
```

in your `bankAccount` header file, and refer to the strings as `std::string`.

```
#ifndef H_bankAccount;
#define H_bankAccount;

#include <string>

class bankAccount
{
public:
    std::string getAcctOwnersName() const;

   ....
```

once it is included in the header, you no longer need to include it in the implementation file.

Comment: Okay I added std::string to my header file code before the string types and it didn't change anyting

Comment: This answer is not useful. Does not provide any connection to or explanation of error message referenced by poster.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when a private member variable and a member function have the same name the IDE gives me the "incompatible" error, perhaps that is what you are experiencing...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occur because it's vary from machine to machine. Your program will work fine if you declare your class and all of its implementations in one file instead doing declaration of class in other file and linked it with your driver file.
Again: This is totally machine dependent error.
In visual studio 2012 you will face this kind of error because it not work for these files while in other versions of vs you will not face any error type exception.

Hope it's worth.....

Comment: This might be one of the error, but what the OP is facing, has already being observed in others answer.